# Phpunit can't be executed from the command line in Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, pear

I've read lots and lots of guides on how to install PHPUnit. I have gotten as far as installing PHPUnit itself plus its dependencies (and some extra packages like PHP_Invoker). However, when I type `phpunit` on the command-line, bash tells me that it couldn't find anything.

I have looked at questions asked previously on here, but the locations seem to be different; even though installation is okay, for example, I find nothing about phpunit under /usr/lib/php/. However, the files are fine under ~/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit, and everything seems to be downloaded.

My problem is running phpunit from the command line to run my tests. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: phpunit is a php library. it's not something you can run standalone.

Comment: I would like to run my tests. As far as I understand, apart from the library, there is a command-line utility I can use. For example, "phpunit tests/unit".

Answer (score 1):

It seems you installed PEAR locally for your user, not system wide.

Now you can either install it system wide (doing all the work again), or simply add the PEAR `bin` directory to your `$PATH` environment variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/pear/share/bin/
```

Then phpunit will be executable without the path.

To find the full path, run

```
$ pear list-files phpunit/phpunit | grep bin
```

Comment: I'd like to thank you for your dry informative answer. Although my problem was not what I had expected it to be and your answer doesn't completely apply to me, I learned many things from your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this question was caused by my mistake. Although pear gave me no errors, for some reason phpunit was not being completely installed (I.E. the `~/pear/bin/phpunit` file was not being created).